# check element type clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that I want to expand/contract with the exception of links.  I have the following code, which works but lacking the exception.  What is the most efficient way of ensuring all elements and areas within the div "expandablediv" cause expand/conract with jquery, with the exception of the  element.

```
$("#expandablediv").click(function () {
                if ($("#withinexpandlediv").is(":hidden")) {
                    $("#withinexpandlediv").fadeIn(50);
                }
                else {
                    $("#withinexpandlediv").fadeOut(50);
                }
            });
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="expandablediv" >
    <div class="ddImage">
        <img src="rightArrow.png" alt="Title">
    </div>
    <div class="ddText">
        Title
    </div>
    <div id="withinexpandlediv" >
        Text contains one or more <a href="mailto:email@links.com"> email links.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML this is acting on? I have done something that I think is similar to what you're trying to do - but you will need to use `height` instead of `display:none` (which is what the fade will do)

Comment: Have you tried doing `if($("#withinexpandlediv").is("div")){}`?

Comment: Added the HTML, if($("#withinexpandlediv").is("div")) is always logically true, indicated by the # sign.

Comment: So, when the user clicks anywhere in the div, you want the entire thing to collapse _except_ for the links - those should remain visible?

Comment: See it in your HTML now.  Mark up helps :)

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see now that you don't want the links to trigger the behavior, everything else does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean you don't want links to trigger the toggle, use [event.target.nodeName](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
        $("#expandablediv").click(function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName == "A") { return; }
            //if ($(e.target).is('a')) { return; } // also works

            if ($("#withinexpandlediv").is(":hidden")) {
                $("#withinexpandlediv").fadeIn(50);
            }
            else {
                $("#withinexpandlediv").fadeOut(50);
            }
        });
```

`nodeName`: http://jsfiddle.net/m7vpk/

`is()`: http://jsfiddle.net/FQuzt/

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
if(!$('#expandablediv').children().has('a')){
    // handle expandsion/contraction here
}
```

Check this link for more details: [jQuery .has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$("#expandablediv").click(function () {
            if ($("#withinexpandlediv").is(":hidden")) {
                $("#withinexpandlediv").fadeIn(50);
            }
            else {
                $("#withinexpandlediv").fadeOut(50);
            }
}).find('a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```