# JQuery .click() selector ignore <a> child elements?

Tags: jquery

I need to fire an event when the user clicks on an element or anything inside it EXCEPT if he clicks on an `<a>` element.

This is what I'm trying now:

```
$( "div:not(a)" ).click(function(e) {
    alert("hello world");
});
```

You can better understand it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/cMBP3/1/

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent execution of parent event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398582/prevent-execution-of-parent-event-handler)

Comment: FYI, the `div:not(a)` selector doesn't make a lot of sense. It means *"select every element with tag name `div` which has not tag name `a`*". Since an element cannot have two tag names, `div:not(a)` is equivalent to `div`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check element type clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797038/check-element-type-clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `div` is never an `a`, this won't work.

You have to check your target element for an `a` tag like this:

```
$('div').click(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if(!$target.is("a") ) {
      alert("hello world");
    }
});
```

I've updated your Fiddle: [Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/Chasmo/cMBP3/12/)

Comment: This looks eerily familiar :) You might want to update your "e" argument to "event" to reflect the object you use in your function.

Comment: Thanks, haven't noticed that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$("div").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'a') alert("hello world");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cMBP3/11/)**

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but hopefully gives you the idea:

```
$(function(){
    $('div').click(function(e){
         if($(e.target).is('a')){
              e.stopPropagation();
         }
    });
});
```